# Ruby 1.9.3 and mac stack size issue

Tags: ruby, macos, recursion, stack-overflow, depth-first-search

Few days ago I encountered a problem while running [Kosaraju's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaraju%27s_algorithm) on a huge graph (almost one million of vertices and 6 millions of edges). The problem was in [DFS (Depth First Search)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) part of the algorithm, which is recoursive - **stack level too deep**. I implemented the algorithm in Ruby and the version of Ruby I used was 1.9.3.

To check the stack size I decided to run simple procedure:

```
def r n
  p n
  r n+1
end

r 1
```

which indicates stack size before termination. I used

```
ulimit -a
```

command to check the stack size and

```
ulimit -s 32768     # Seems like this is the maximum stack size for mac OS
ulimit -s unlimited # => Invalid argument error
```

to change stack size. Even after I changed stack size r-procedure shown the same number - 8193. After I change Ruby to 1.8.7 the last number became 19177.

Eventually I found a friend who uses Ubuntu and stack size there is unlimited. I run the Kosaraju's algorithm successfully.

How can I do it on mac?

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax to change the stack size limit is:

```
ulimit -S -s 32768
```

On OS X 10.7.3 `ulimit -S -s unlimited` will set the limit to 65532.

Comment: On 10.6.8 it leads to 32768. But the question is - why it depends on Ruby version?

Comment: Your code does not measure the stack size, it does count the number of recursions. Stack size is measured in bytes, maybe Ruby 1.8.7 has smaller stack sizes and can therefore recurse more often.

Answer (score 0):

Besides OS X `ulimit` value, stack size in a Ruby program can be controlled by these environment variables: `RUBY_THREAD_VM_STACK_SIZE`, `RUBY_THREAD_MACHINE_STACK_SIZE`, `RUBY_FIBER_VM_STACK_SIZE` and `RUBY_FIBER_MACHINE_STACK_SIZE`. You can check the default values in an irb session:

```
RubyVM::DEFAULT_PARAMS
=> {:thread_vm_stack_size=>1048576,
    :thread_machine_stack_size=>1048576,
    :fiber_vm_stack_size=>131072,
    :fiber_machine_stack_size=>524288}
```

So, if you want to change the VM stack size to 2097152, for instance:

```
RUBY_THREAD_VM_STACK_SIZE=2097152 ruby script.rb
```

But, in this specific case, I was implementing the very same algorithm in Ruby and had the same problem, and increasing the stack size wasn't enough. The solution that worked for me was implementing the algorithm without recursion.

Comment: Those varaiables are available from ruby 2.0.0